# Trouble setting camera position in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, camera, position

I'm attempting to set the camera position in Unity through code.  I have a simple 2D game and there's not much programming so far.  I've attached a script to the camera, and in that script I've added this function:

```
  void Update()
    {
    Transform transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    transform.position.Set(position.x + 1, position.y + 1, position.z);
    }
```

My expectation is that this would create a smooth scrolling toward the bottom right corner.  However, after checking via breakpoints, the transform.position always reports (0, 0, -10), even after setting it.  The camera object is a stand alone and not a child of anything else in the scene.  Am I setting the position wrong or getting the camera's GameObject wrong?

I've also tried:

- transform.SetPosition(); - doesn't exist
- transform.SetPositionAndRotation(); - no effect
- transform.position.x = 0; - not allowed
- transform.position = new Vector3(position.x + 1, position.y + 1, position.z) - no effect

Comment: Have you tried not to create a local variable called transform but use transform directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several misconceptions here.

First off, every `Component` and `GameObject` already has a pre-cached `transform`, property, so you *never* have to write `GetComponent<Transform>()`. Deleting this line changes nothing, since all it does is shadow the existing `transform` property that gives the same value:

```
Transform transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
```

Next, `transform.position` is a *getter/setter* property. When you read or write to it, you're really calling a function. The getter you call on a read...

1. Takes the transform's internally stored local position...
2. Gets the corresponding world position by transforming it by any transformations higher up in the hierarchy...
3. Returns to you a *copy* of that value.

Calling `position.Set()` on a *copy* of the data does not make the change propagate back to the original transform: it has no idea you changed anything, because you didn't ask *it* to change.

Thirdly, you never want to add a constant offset to a position in `Update()`, because that function is called at a variable framerate. To get smooth motion, you should scale the movement by the amount of time elapsed since the previous `Update()` frame.

Lastly, moving +1 in y is moving up, not down, in Unity's coordinate system. If you want to move down, *decrease* y.

Putting these together:

```cs
public float movementSpeed = 1f;

void Update() {
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    Vector3 shift = new Vector3(1, -1, 0) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = position + shift;

    // Or, as another answer notes,
    // transform.Translate(shift, Space.World)
    // accomplishes the same thing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `transform.Translate(movement_dir)`
where `movement_dir` is a vector you can define outside of `Update` if it's going to be a constant.

However you might want to multiply `movement_dir` by `Time.deltaTime`, otherwise it might not be as smooth as you'd like due to variations in FPS

see [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)